# Segmentation fault when using C++ array in for loop

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop, segmentation-fault

I am trying to write a C++ code to sort numbers from an input file into two arrays, one even and one odd. I am having a few related issues with this code. Firstly if I remove the line `cout << "even " << evenArray[nEven] << endl;` or `cout << "odd " << oddArray[nOdd] << endl;` then I get `exited, segmentation fault.` If I do include these lines then the code will run as expected printing every number and the associated array. However, there are always a few numbers in the code that print as either `even 6299840` or `odd 0` (for a line that is not 0, lines that are 0 correctly sort as even) When I print the variable `number` it prints correctly but when I print `evenArray[nEven]` the error occurs. Finally, `cout << oddArray[0] << endl << evenArray[0];` prints both even and odd as 17. While this is correct for odd, it is not for even. Both arrays print the same values in the correct order for the odd array from index 0-3. At index 4 odd prints the next in the sequence and even prints `6299840.` I am using Repl to run this code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main() {


ifstream inFile; 
int nEven = 0, nOdd = 0;
int number;
int evenArray[nEven]
int oddArray[nOdd];
inFile.open("input.txt");
if (!inFile) 
  cout << "Cannot open file, terminating program"<< endl;
else
{
  while(!inFile.eof() && inFile >> number) {
      if (number % 2 == 0) {
        evenArray[nEven] = number;
        cout << "even " << evenArray[nEven] << endl;
        nEven += 1;
        sumEven += number;
      }
      else {
        oddArray[nOdd] = number;
        cout << "odd " << oddArray[nOdd] <<endl;
        nOdd += 1;
        sumOdd += number;
      } //end else
  } //end of while
inFile.close();
cout << oddArray[0] << endl << evenArray[0];

return 0;
}//end of main
```

Here is the data I am using.

```
46 30 82 90 56 17 95 16 48 26
4 58 0 78 92 60 12 21 63 47
19 41 90 85 14 -9 52 71 79 16
80 51 95 102 34 10 79 95 61 92
89 88 66 18 6 63 66 64 39 5
```

This is the output:

```
46  even 46
30  even 30
82  even 82
90  even 90
56  even 56
17  odd 17
95  odd 95
16  even 16
48  even 48
26  even 26
4   even 4
58  even 58
0   even 0
78  even 78
92  even 92
60  even 60
12  even 12
21  odd 21
63  odd 63
47  odd 47
19  odd 19
41  odd 41
90  even 90
85  odd 85
14  even 14
-9  odd -9
52  even 52
71  odd 71
79  odd 79
16  even 16
80  even 80
51  odd 51
95  odd 6299840
102 even 102
34  even 34
10  even 6299840
79  odd 0
95  odd 95
61  odd 61
92  even 0
89  odd 89
88  even 88
66  even 66
18  even 18
6   even 6
63  odd 63
66  even 66
64  even 64
39  odd 39
5   odd 5
17
17
```

Comment: `int evenArray[nEven], oddArray[nOdd]` is illegal in C++.

Comment: I just separated it into two lines and am still having the same issue.

Comment: That's not why it's illegal. First, they're VLAs (variable length automatic arrays) which are not supported by the language standard. Second, even if your compiler does support them by non-standard extension, ask yourself "what is the value of `nEven` and `nOdd` at the time those arrays are declared?" ` Changing those (`nEven` and `nOdd`) later doesn't magically resize the arrays. The solution is to use a container literally designed for the purpose you seek: `std::vector<int>`. Better still, look closely at your code and seriously consider whether you even need those arrays in the first place

Comment: that fixed it. thank you so much